# How to add cross-references to picture in Apache POI Word?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to create a document with text and pictures using Apache POI. Some part of text must be cross-reference to the pictures. I tried following the answer of this question changing the `addExternalRelationship` method to `addRelationship` without success:

[How to create hyperlinks in Apache POI Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192481/how-to-create-a-existing-file-link-in-poi-word-format)

Edited: below is my attempt after studying the code from:

[Generate Inter-Document Hyperlink with Apache POI in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658950/generate-inter-document-hyperlink-with-apache-poi-in-java)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.BreakType;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.UnderlinePatterns;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHyperlinkRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBookmark;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STFldCharType;

public class CrossReference {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        document.createParagraph();

        document.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);

        XWPFParagraph pictureParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        pictureParagraph.setSpacingAfter(0);

        XWPFRun pictureRun = pictureParagraph.createRun();
        String imgPath = "img.png";
        pictureRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgPath), 
                XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, 
                imgPath, 
                Units.toEMU(288), 
                Units.toEMU(288));

        String anchor = "anchor";

        XWPFParagraph captionParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun captionRun = captionParagraph.createRun();
        captionRun.setText("Figure ");
        CTBookmark bookmark = captionParagraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkStart();
        bookmark.setName(anchor);
        bookmark.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
        captionParagraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.BEGIN);
        captionParagraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("SEQ Figure \\* ARABIC");
        captionParagraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.END);
        captionParagraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkEnd().setId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

        CTHyperlink ctHyperlink = paragraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
        ctHyperlink.setAnchor(anchor);
        XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun = new XWPFHyperlinkRun(ctHyperlink, 
                ctHyperlink.addNewR(), paragraph);
        hyperlinkRun.setText("Figure 1");
        hyperlinkRun.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.docx"));
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        document.close();
    }
}
```

However, in document.xml from docx, the paragraph obtained is:

```
  <w:p>
     <w:hyperlink w:anchor="anchor">
        <w:r>
           <w:rPr>
              <w:u w:val="single" />
           </w:rPr>
           <w:t>Figure 1</w:t>
        </w:r>
     </w:hyperlink>
  </w:p>
  <w:p />
```

While I expected something like the XML presented below (obtained by adding reference manually using LibreOffice Writer). The problem with the hyperlink approach is that its text is fixed and it won't be updated if the document is edited.

```
  <w:p>
     <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Normal" />
        <w:rPr />
     </w:pPr>
     <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Figure </w:t>
     </w:r>
     <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin" />
     </w:r>
     <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:instrText>REF Ref_Figure0_number_only \h</w:instrText>
     </w:r>
     <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate" />
     </w:r>
     <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:t>1</w:t>
     </w:r>
     <w:r>
        <w:rPr />
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end" />
     </w:r>
  </w:p>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658950/generate-inter-document-hyperlink-with-apache-poi-in-java/53670881#53670881 for how to create a document internal link. Of course the bookmarked target paragraph also may contain a picture.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you for indicating this question. In fact it contains the solution to this problem. I will mark it as duplicated.

Comment: @AxelRichter After applying your solution I found out that it doesn't address my problem. The XML generated is different from what I expected. I edited the question to show that it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the solution to the problem is obtained with bookmarks instead of hyperlinks:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.BreakType;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xmlschema.SpaceAttribute.Space;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBookmark;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTOnOff;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSimpleField;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTText;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STFldCharType;

public class CrossReference {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();

        document.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);

        XWPFParagraph pictureParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        pictureParagraph.setSpacingAfter(0);

        XWPFRun pictureRun = pictureParagraph.createRun();
        String imgPath = "img.png";
        pictureRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgPath), 
                XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, 
                imgPath, 
                Units.toEMU(288), 
                Units.toEMU(288));

        XWPFParagraph captionParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun captionRun = captionParagraph.createRun();
        CTText ctText = captionRun.getCTR().addNewInstrText();
        ctText.setSpace(Space.PRESERVE);
        ctText.setStringValue("Figure ");
        CTBookmark bookmark = captionParagraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkStart();
        bookmark.setName("Figure-1");
        bookmark.setId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

        CTSimpleField ctSimpleField = captionParagraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple();
        ctSimpleField.setInstr("SEQ Figure \\* ARABIC");
        CTR ctR = ctSimpleField.addNewR();
        ctR.addNewRPr().setNoProof(CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance());
        ctR.addNewT().setStringValue(Integer.toString(1));

        captionParagraph.getCTP().addNewBookmarkEnd().setId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
        captionParagraph.setSpacingAfter(0);

        paragraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.BEGIN);

        ctText = paragraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewInstrText();
        ctText.setSpace(Space.PRESERVE);
        ctText.setStringValue("REF Figure-1 \\h");

        paragraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.SEPARATE);

        ctText = paragraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewT();
        ctText.setSpace(Space.PRESERVE);
        ctText.setStringValue("Figure ");

        ctR = paragraph.createRun().getCTR();
        ctR.addNewRPr().setNoProof(CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance());
        ctR.addNewT().setStringValue(Integer.toString(1));

        paragraph.createRun().getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.END);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.docx"));
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        document.close();
    }

}
```